# Is there any way to make a div by using pure css?

Tags: html, css

I'm editing a wordpress site that I dont have access to any of the HTML and only css. I need to input just two lines of text sort of like a "div". Is there any way to do this by only using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements like this.

```css
p:before {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  content: 'this is from css';
}
```

```html
<p>hello there</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it with :before or :after pseudo elements?

```
div.class-name:after {
    content: 'text goes here';
    display: block;
    [style further as necessary]
}
```